# Do Bundle Links in Experience Manager open webpages by default?

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, workflow, bundles

On one of our training setups (Electridion on SDL Tridion 2013), clicking on Pages in the Bundle workflow list opens a new browser tab to the corresponding webpage in Staging.

Clicking on Pages in a Bundle from the Activity pane in the slide out menu opens form view, as expected.

- Is opening the webpage (not Tridion page form view) default behavior in Experience Manager (or maybe it's the task list)?
- Did it differ before where links opened the *Tridion* pages?

I might be wrong, but I thought at one point (~Tridion 2013 GA) that opening a bundle link would open the form view when in Experience Manager.

To be clear, I like the direct links to the webpages and want to make sure I didn't miss this functionality or give out the wrong information.