# Which page opens when click a component in Related Item on XPM?

Tags: experience-manager, 2013-sp1, workflow

On Experience Manager, workflow activities appear on the top right of browser, and those include "Related Items".
When there is a component in "Related Items", and clicking the component, then a page that contains it opens in XPM.

If there are more than 2 pages that contain same componet, how does XPM decide to open which page?

Tridion manual contains following line

- If the item is a Component that has been published to the Web site, Experience Manager opens a Web page containing that Component in a new browser window.

I guess it's same logic as Dynamic Linking in CD API.
If so, where is "current page"?
(Dynamic Linking has "current page" parameter to decide which page is the "closest" to it.)

Regards,

Comment: Good question. I was trying to confirm if [related pages in (XPM) workflow opened website pages by default](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/10966/46) and I'm thinking this is newish behavior. I understand the related items list is based on items in the bundle, which if dealing with Pages and Components, do not have Component Templates either. So I'd suspect this might be based on Where Used, but I'm not 100% sure yet.

Answer (score 2):

Experience Manager looks at all the Pages that use the Component and redirects to the one that uses the Component Template with the highest Priority.

There are other factors at work, such as: whether the user can actually read the various items ***, if the items are editable in Experience Manager, and whether they are published to the current target.

*** So different users might get different results, but that doesn't really matter since the goal is just to allow them to edit the Component in context.

Comment: Ah, that's a new type of "resolving" to know. Were these links always in context, redirecting to an XPM page? I thought the Workflow related item links opened up Component form views at one point.

Comment: I can't recall exactly when it was introduced. I think it might have been there back when it was SiteEdit, but then removed in the redesign and reintroduced later. But I could be totally wrong about that.